# How to enable Onboard Graphics for a GIGABYTE B450 PRO

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios

Today I ran into a problem with setting up my 2nd screeen. After searching I figured out that the onboard graphics has to be enabled in the BIOS (it is not showing up in device manager).

Using <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> in the BIOS won't show any new options and there is nothing saying PCIe or VGA ord Display settings.

Does anyone knows what it is called and where exactly it is located? I'm using a GIGABYTE AORUS B450 PRO updated with the latest drivers.

Comment: its a Ryzen2700x, tbh no idea if it has onboard gpu

Comment: Edit your question so all vital information is in the body of your question instead of a comment

Comment: What graphics are you using at the moment? Have you tried removing the external card?

Comment: Please read this: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029)

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone knows what its called and where exactly its located ? Im using a GIGABYTE AORUS B450 PRO updated with the latest drivers.

Based on the specifications of your CPU, it does not have a built-in GPU, which means you will unable to turn on your onboard video since there isn’t one in your system as it’s currently  configured.

You will need to connect any displays to your Nvidia or AMD PCIe GPU instead.  Connecting a display to the HDMI or DVI-D port on your motherboard will not result in any video being displayed due to the CPU not having a GPU.

Source: [Ryzen 2700x](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-2700x)